# Tweetinvi. The name 'CredentialsCreator' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

After adding the `Tweetinvi` library using `nuget` to my `asp.net application` and trying an example:

I made sure to add the `references` such as:

```
using Tweetinvi;
using Tweetinvi.Models;
var applicationCredentials = CredentialsCreator.GenerateApplicationCredentials(ConsumerKey, 
ConsumerSecret);
```

I get the following error: The name '`CredentialsCreator`' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the version that you are using but `CredentialsCreator` is old logic that is no longer used.

You can do the following now :

```cs
new ConsumerCredentials("CONSUMER_TOKEN", "CONSUMER_SECRET")
{
    ApplicationOnlyBearerToken = "BEARER_TOKEN"
};

// or if you want to set the credentials
Auth.SetApplicationOnlyCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "BEARER_TOKEN");

// if you do not have the bearer token and want tweetinvi to retrieve it for you
Auth.SetApplicationOnlyCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", true);
```

I hope this helps you